# wrong coin send towards Solana wallet on ledger,

Tags: solana, wallet

By accident I did sent USDT from my Bybit account towards my solana address on my ledger Nano
So I sent the wrong coin to my solana address
I do own the sender and the receiver address
Can I correct this somehowe or are my USDT's lost forever.
I do have the TXID
Could you help me out

Thanks in advance

I tryed to contact Bybit but the transaction was succeeded, and therefore they can not help.